# Is the regular expression /(?:(?:foo)|(?:bar))/ functionally equivalent to /(?:foo|bar)/?

Tags: regex

I am tewaking a regular expression that is making my eyes sore. I would like to simplify it.
Is the regular expression

```
/(?:(?:foo)|(?:bar))/
```

functionally equivalent to

```
/(?:foo|bar)/
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `?:` is for non grouping capture.

Comment: Thank you. My regex is now much smaller. :)